# jQuery autocomplete not firing for one of three on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have three autocomplete textboxes on a page and I cannot figure out why one of them does not get the source data, the function is never fired but the other two are.

> Here is my JS:

```
 $("#txtUserId").autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 0,
        autoFocus: true,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                data: { 'data': request.term },
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetAllUsers")',
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (obj) {
                        return {
                            value: obj.Value,
                            label: obj.Text
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            neworold = "old";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetUser")',
                data: { userid: ui.item.value },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.UserId == null) {
                        $("#lblError").text("User was not found");
                        $("#MessageDialog").dialog({ title: "User Maintenance" });
                        $("#MessageDialog").dialog("open");
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#txtUserName").val(data.UserName);
                        $("#txtUserRole").val(data.UserRole);
                        $("#chkUserAdmin").prop("checked", data.Admin);
                        $("#chkUserTrans").prop("checked", data.Trans);
                        $("#chkUserReports").prop("checked", data.Reports);
                        $("#txtUserId").val(data.UserId);
                        $("#txtFirstName").val(data.FirstName);
                        $("#txtLastName").val(data.LastName);
                        $("#txtInventoryRole").val(data.InventoryRole);
                        $("#txtDept").val(data.Department);
                        $("#lblRoleDesc").text(data.UserRoleDescription);
                        $("#lblInvRoleDesc").text(data.RoleDescription);
                    }

                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    var err = xhr.responseText;
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        }
    }).focus(function () {
        $("#txtUserId").autocomplete('search', $("#txtUserId").val());
    })
```

> **HTML:**

```
 <td>
            <b style="color:red">*</b>Find User ID or Enter New:<br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.UserId)
        </td>
        <td>

            @Html.TextBoxForWithTitle(x=>x.UserId, new { @id = "txtUserId", style = "text-transform:uppercase", @class = "userModel, textboxsize"})
        </td>
```

No matter where I move the box it never kicks off the source function.  My action:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetAllUsers(string data)
    {
        List<TextValuePair> items = GetAllUsers();
        var result1 = items.Where(item => item.toUpper().Contains(data.ToUpper())).ToList();
        return Json(result1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Any ideas?  The very puzzling thing is this was working last week and is not now.  Unfortunately I do not have a code repository so I cannot get an earlier version.

Comment: do see see the request in the console (in crome right click on the console and check the log XMHttpRequest them you will see the requests in case you dont, it will help you debugging

Comment: If I change the ID of the box it works.  There must be some other field with that name on the page and since everything is in a dialog I cannot find it.

Comment: you have 3 text boxes with the same ID `#txtUserId` ?

Comment: Is it necessary to get new source all the time? Otherwise you could call it once, and denn init the AC. And the thing with the ID's which might cause problems, use a class instead...